# JSON Parser doesn't get whole code

Tags: objective-c, json

I am using the Foursquare API to get near places to the Users location. A sample response for only one  place is [here](http://textsave.de/ymJ).

Now when I parse the response using JSONkit, the parser "forgets" the first part. The data I get begins from the tag "canonicalUrl". But I need the first part of the response too. Iam using this code to parse the data:

```
-(void)getDataWithLongitude:(float)longitude andLatitude:(float)latitude {

    // Get current date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];


    NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=MY_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&v=%@&locale=de&limit=10&venuePhotos=1", dateString];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theURL];

    [request setURL:url];

    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [data objectFromJSONData];
    NSArray *array = [resultsDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"response.venues"];

    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
```

I used now NSJSONSerialization for the parsing but with no other result.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

Comment: Does the response data really start with `response: { ...`? In that case it is not valid JSON...

Comment: But keys should be enclosed in quotation marks `{ "meta" : ...` or is that just displayed wrongly? - I don't know JSONkit, why don't you use NSJSONSerialization, which is already available in Foundation?

Comment: Because I read that JSONkit ist faster than NSJSONSerialization. I try NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: You can check the JSON response at http://jsonlint.com.

Comment: Yes I checked just seconds ago, you're right with the quotation marks. But they're included in the real JSON. The code I posted was formatted by a JSON viewer extension of chrome. I have updated the file http://textsave.de/1mJ

Comment: I have tested NSJSONSerialization with a text file containing your JSON data, and the result looked OK.

Comment: JSONKit works as well without problems. `resultsDictionary` contains the complete response. Did you mix-up the contents of `resultsDictionary` and `array`?

Comment: See my updated question, it doesn't work with NSJSONSerialization either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33454/discussion-between-martin-r-and-sebastian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, both JSONKit and NSJSONSerialization parse the
FourSquare response correctly.

The only reason that some parts *seemed* to be missing is that the
dictionary key/value pairs were displayed in a different order than in the JSON data.